# How to append hidden field value to drop down using jQuery?

Tags: jquery, asp.net

I am trying to assign value from hidden filed to drop down in order to keep my drop down selected value when user post back or navigate and came back to same page. Can you please suggest me on this. Below is the code,

```
function pageLoad(sender, e) {

        var hiddenvalue= document.getElementById('<%= hfIDType.ClientID%>').value;
        if (hiddenvalue!= "") {
            $("#iddlIDType").val("hiddenvalue");
        }
    }
```

Comment: Since `hiddenvalue` is a variable pass it directly. Remove quotes i.e. `$("#iddlIDType").val(hiddenvalue);`

Comment: Tried with this but drop down selected value not retained if i go to other page and come back.

Comment: when this function get called pageLoad???

Comment: when i go to other page and hit cancel button from that page and when i see my selected DD id type value it's not been present it is cleared. I want keep that value selected.

Comment: @Shiva - if you go to other page and come back in that senario view state get remove and that will not work ....if you want to make it work than store value in cookies,storage (client side management) or server side session

Answer (score 0):

you have to co like this , make use of [ClientScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bahh2fef(v=vs.110).aspx), and register script from page

```
public void Page_Load(Object sender, EventArgs e)
{

 Type cstype = this.GetType();
 ClientScriptManager cs = Page.ClientScript;

// Check to see if the startup script is already registered.
if (!cs.IsStartupScriptRegistered(cstype, "pageload"))
{
 string script = " $( document ).ready(function() { var hiddenvalue= document.getElementById('<%=hfIDType.ClientID%>').value; "+
    "if (hiddenvalue!= '') {"+
        "$('#iddlIDType').val(hiddenvalue);"+
    "} }";

  String cstext1 = "alert('Hello World');";
  cs.RegisterClientScriptBlock (cstype, "pageload", script , true);
}
```

}

Comment: Thanks Rana for your reply but i am not able to fix my problem with the given code i think i am done the same thing in the script section(in UI). Please correct me if i am wrong.

Comment: @Shiva - well my mean to say in asp.net you should make use of `RegisterClientScriptBlock ` when you want to execute your client side script on page load ...

Comment: Yes Rana it's calling and debug point is getting executed in page load but value is not setting to drop down.

Comment: @Shiva - i forgot to include `$( document ).ready(function() {` , included now can you please try now

Comment: No Pranay actually i was getting script errors so i just handle from server side. Thanks for your time.